# Forward/backward compatibility of glibc and the kernel

Tags: linux, compatibility, kernel, glibc

Suppose you have glibc 2.5 compiled with kernel headers 2.6.18

1. Is it safe to run this glibc with Linux kernel 2.6.32?
2. Is it safe to run this glibc with Linux kernel 2.6.9?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking if it's safe to run software built on EL5 on either Fedora or on EL4...

Comment: More accurately, "if it's safe to run software built on EL5 on either `Fedora w/glibc 2.5` or on `EL4 w/glibc 2.5`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should be possible to run older software on a newer glibc and kernel, although depending on how old it is you may have to set various `$LD_*` options; see the `ld.so(8)` man page for more details.

Running software with an older glibc usually does not work; using an older kernel may or may not work, depending on what kernel features it uses.